# indexedDB function return import/export across modules

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm still a beginner so I hope this makes sense.

I am trying to export a return variable from a function with an IndexedDB transaction/cursor to another module with a get transaction however that request is always undefined. Is it possible to get the value of IndexedDB function across to other modules within the same domain?

**db.js** - function I am exporting

```
...
function getAllData() {
    // can use getAll() however not as efficient.
    // let data = [];
    let data = [];
    let store = db.transaction("forms").objectStore("forms");
    store.openCursor().onsuccess = (event) => {
        let cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            console.log("FORM name is " + cursor.value.name + " and form counter is " + cursor.key);
            // data.push(cursor.value.name);
            data.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            console.log("All entries retrieved");
            console.log("the data form.name is " + data);
            console.log("the data is " + data.length);
            return data.length;

        }

    }

    store.openCursor().onerror = event => {
        console.log("Error in getting all data " + event.target.errorCode);
    }

};

export { getAllData } ;
```

**a.js**

```
import { getAlldData } from './db.js'

(() => {

function getIndex() {
    let formData = getAllData();    
    console.log("the counter is " + formData); // shows formData as undefined
}
}

)();
```

Is it possible to get the return value of **db.js** getAllData() in **a.js** formData? They console.log correctly in db.js

Comment: You need to learn about asynchronous JavaScript, and/or learn about how to use a callback function, or begin working with promises. If you learn some of those things, it is very doable.

Comment: Thanks for info. I created a callback function that did the trick. Struggling to get my head around Promises with IndexedDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you got it working with a callback. Here is an example of using a promise.

```js
export function getAllData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let data = [];
    let store = db.transaction("forms").objectStore("forms");

    const request = store.openCursor();
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      let cursor = event.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
        data.push(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
      } else {
         resolve(data);
      }
    };

    request.onerror = event => {
      reject(new Error('Error getting all data'));
    };
  });
}

// and then to use it in another module you do this:

import { getAllData } from 'file';

getAllData().then(data => {
  console.log('loaded %d rows', data.length);
  for (const row of data) {
    console.log('row of data:', JSON.stringify(row));
  }
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('got an error :( - ', error.message);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer actually helped me to understand how to create my own Promises and consume them in different modules.